# Exposure to accoustic ceiling dust

Tags: ceiling, asbestos, acoustic

I scraped the acoustic ceiling to obtain a sample to take for testing not realizing the precautions that I should have taken (I took none). I scraped about a teaspoon or so into a ziplock bag. Zipped the bag then set it inside another open bag in the floorboard of my car to drive to the testing center (about 20 minutes away). I ran the A/C and I know there was some dust on the outside of the bag. The test was positive 2% Crysotile. I took a shower when I got back and once I realized I didn't do this properly I opened up the car and have since run the A/C on fresh air with the windows open but did drive it awhile on recirculate before I realized the problem. Please advise!!

Comment: Did the test come back positive for asbestos?

Comment: Unless you start snorting a teaspoon a few times a day, your doctor will probably say take two aspirin and call in the morning.  Next time use a mask.

Comment: You're fine, such a tiny amount couldn't possibly harm you. Only long term, industrial exposure causes problems.    If you're still concerned, simply wipe down the hard services and vacuum the soft ones (like the carpet and seats (if cloth)).

Comment: @crip659 They don't say take 2 aspirin any more. Can't - aspirin can cause bleeding and other problems. Take 2 Tylenol. But make sure they are from a double-sealed tamper-proof container.

Comment: Or to put it another way: If you work in a nuclear power plant, you need to wear a dosimeter and take precautions. But everyone else can eat an occasional banana and get a dental x-ray. [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/radiation/) (though radiation, not asbestos, but asbestos is similar in that a little won't kill you but a lot over a long time will)

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Guess I am showing my age.  I remember when tamper proof came out.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why professional testers wear bunny suits and HEPA masks on youtube videos is because it's an occupational hazard, meaning these measures protect against exposure if it's your occupation. Professionals and their employers have to operate by health & safety regulations for the sake of their insurance and to prevent any long term effects from persistent exposure (a DIY cleanup, a summer job, a career).

This substance is not toxic or radioactive, and your minimal *incidental* exposure from taking a sample (if any) is very likely not a factor.

> Regulations and guidelines have been installed to keep the level of asbestos exposure at a minimum and are necessary among those who are in danger of being exposed in the work place.

Ref https://gpwlaw.com/uncategorized/the-permissible-exposure-limit-and-the-threshold-limit-value-for-asbestos-exposure/

And

[image]

Ref https://www.osha.gov/sites/default/files/publications/OSHA3507.pdf

The 0.1 value is very very low, but remember it is not value for a single incident, but for long term exposure. The 1.0 value is a maximum excursion value, but again for repeated exposure.